# non finitely generated group with finite abelianization

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose $K$ is a non finitely generated and residually finite group, is it possible that $K$ has finite abelianization, *i.e.* the quotient group $K \big/ [K,K]$ is finite?

If we take $K$ to be the infinitely generated free group, then the abelianization (which is the free abelian group) would be infinite.

On the other hand, if we take $K$ to be an infinitely generated abelian group, then the abelianization would clearly be infinite.

Then I thought that maybe $K$ can be a semidirect product of two groups? I have not seen many examples of infinitely generated semidirect product groups. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun sorry I'm new to this website, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Take your favourite perfect group $G\neq1$ and the direct product $H = \prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty G_n$, where each $G_n=G$. The commutators of $H$ are taken coordinate-wise, so now $[H, H] = \prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty [G_n, G_n] = \prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty G_n$, and so $H/[H, H]=1$ but $H$ itself is not finitely generated.

---

Edit (YCor) as mentioned in the comments, the above-claimed equality $[H,H]=\prod [G_n,G_n]$ can fail in general. It holds if (and only if) there exists $m$ such that every element of $[G,G]$ is a product of $\le m$ commutators. This trivially holds if $G$ is finite.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun less effort for everyone to not go through a million questions trying to find what the asker *may* have been after. In this case the question at least was understandable. You can go find the duplicate yourself.

Comment: That's beside the point. The problem with the question was that it had no context (before it was edited).

Comment: Please read the meta announcement.

Comment: It is not true in general that the commutator subgroup of an infinite product is the product of the corresponding commutator subgroups... The latter may be strictly larger, as elements of the commutator subgroup of the product are necessarily bounded in length, and the same is not true for the product of commutator subgroups.

Comment: For example, take $H$ free of countable rank with generators $x_i$. Let $g_n = [x_1,x_2]\cdots[x_{2n-1},x_{2n}]$. If $G$ is the product of countably many copies of $H$, then $(g_1,g_2,g_3,\ldots)$ is not in the commutator subgroup of $G$, but is in the product of the commutator subgroups. While this is not a perfect group, it does show that you need to be careful in asserting that $[\prod G_n,\prod G_n] = \prod [G_n,G_n]$.

Comment: It should be the direct sum, not the direct product. Also, you need to use, say, finite $G$, to ensure residual finiteness of $H$.

Comment: This group $\prod_n G_n$ is better denoted $G^\mathbf{N}$. It is residually finite iff $G$ is residually finite. It is perfect if and only if $G$ is **uniformly perfect** (e.g., $G$ is finite and perfect). If instead one picks $G^{(\mathbf{N})}$, the direct sum, it is perfect iff $G$ is perfect (and infinitely generated unless $G=1$).